# How to get Dynamic Url from firebase

Tags: java, android, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, android-deep-link

[image]We are not access share url from firebase using "https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive"

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
        .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                // Get deep link from result (may be null if no link is found)
                Uri deepLink = null;
                if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                    deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();

                    Log.e("deepLink",""+deepLink.toString());
                }


                // Handle the deep link. For example, open the linked
                // content, or apply promotional credit to the user's
                // account.
                // ...

                // ...
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
            }
        });
```

this method of firebase is allways return null in "onSuccess".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you need to make sure you `URI` is formulated like

`https://your_subdomain.page.link/?link=your_deep_link&apn=package_name[&amv=minimum_version][&afl=fallback_link]`

method `getDynamicLink` returns null if a dynamic link is not previously captured or is in the Uri, the above link format is not necessarily to be like that but it should match to the intent filters you have previously defined.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity android:name=".EntryChoiceActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".java.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <!-- [START link_intent_filter] -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data
                    android:host="link"
                    android:scheme="your_subdomain.page.link"/>
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

also you should add query parameters to the link field in the firebase console, `https://your_subdomain.page.link/?link=your_deep_link&apn=package_name[&amv=minimum_version][&afl=fallback_link]` and deep link remain short `https://your_subdomain.page.link/example` now to reproduce an adb test for a intent filters like:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activities.MyActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <!-- ATTENTION: This intent was auto-generated. Follow instructions at
    https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio to publish your Android app deep links. -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- ATTENTION: This data URL was auto-generated. We recommend that you use the HTTP scheme.
        TODO: Change the host or pathPrefix as necessary. -->
        <data
            android:host="link"
            android:scheme="your_subdomain.page.link" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

use:

`adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "your_subdomain.page.link://link?key=category_parent_id\&value=92\&title=test" com.app_name.android`

Hope this help thanks.